# How to Change or make new Launch Image programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a loyalty card app. When the customer runs the app for the first time he's prompted to import the image of his physical card he received via email. From there on I’d like the launch screen (splash screen) to display his loyalty card to maximize speed as this is what the app will do when VC loads.

How to change the image for the launch screen programmatically (using Swift)?

Thank you, Andrej

Comment: You can't. Unfortunately there is no API to change the launch image. You can always file a feature request at [ Bug Report](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible option is to shown user's loyality card in

```
- (BOOL)application:(iOApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController new] autorelease];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Put a default image
    // until we decide if the sign up screen needs to be displayed.
    UIImageView *defaultImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage mydefaultLaunchImage]];
    [_window.rootViewController.view addSubview:defaultImageView];
    [defaultImageView release];

    //Perform application init asynchronously and remove default image after.
    //..........
}
```

But, if application was launched, system shows screenshot of it when restoring from background.
As described [Being a Responsible Background App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) section of Background Execution programming guide,

> Remove sensitive information from views before moving to the background. When an app transitions to the background, the system takes a snapshot of the app’s main window, which it then presents briefly when transitioning your app back to the foreground. Before returning from your applicationDidEnterBackground: method, you should hide or obscure passwords and other sensitive personal information that might be captured as part of the snapshot.

What you can do here is add user's loyality card image on top of your view hierarchy so iOS captures screenshot of it.